# Code Coverage 0% Cant add to salesforce

Tags: trigger, code, code-coverage

I'm just trying to put this code into production and its not letting me!

```
     Trigger OppProdLine on Opportunity (before update) {

        list<opportunity> sl = trigger.new;

        list<opportunityLineItem> slnu = new list<opportunityLineItem>([select id ,product2.name, opportunityId from opportunitylineitem where opportunityId =: trigger.new[0].id]);

        string productName='';

        for(opportunityLineItem opp : slnu){

         productName += opp.product2.name +';'; // + operator for concatenation.

        }

        for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){

         opp.Opportunity_Prod__c = productName;


}


}
```

I found this online and it works perfect in sandbox but it keeps saying I have 0% code coverage when I try to put it into normal salesforce. I just need this to be able to work in regular salesforce. Also I have zero coding exp.
Any help much appreciated 
Thanks :)

Comment: You need to write a [test class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_test.htm) to cover the code beside that i would love to hear the difference between normal and regular salesforce.

Comment: haha sry meant production. Im still a little confused on a test class, am I writing the same code twice once to test and once to run?

Comment: A test class is a class you write which contains a method which performs some DML operation that will utilize the code. If your code checks for a certain value in the field and changes it, and handle it differently if the value does not exist, your test class will create two records where one has that value and the other does not. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Comment: So why is test code coverage necessary to deploy code into production? I get it helps identify logical fallacies, and keep poorly written code from being used in production, but is that it?

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that we won't be able to help you with this.  The error you are getting is not because your current code is untested, but because the code in your organization is untested.  In order to perform deployments, Salesforce requires you to maintain at least 75% code coverage (by lines of code.)  If your org is at 0, something is either very wrong or your developers never wrote tests to begin with.

Comment: Does that still matter if I'm only trying to deploy one trigger? or do I need to fix all of our code first before I can deploy anything?

Comment: You'll have to fix all of the other code, unfortunately.